# Which time expression should come first?

Tags: grammar

In the following phrase, which time expression should come first? Or are both correct?

> between 150,000 and 750,000 years ago.
> between 750,000 and 150,000 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should quote the smaller number first:

> between 150,000 and 750,000 years ago

This is because the two numbers are *amounts* of time, and when quoting a range between two amounts it is logical to present the smaller number first.

Examples I found in articles:

> - Vaccine development is a long, complex process, often lasting **10-15** years
> - What number is halfway between **10 and 15**?
> - Тhose with **6-15** years of tenure...

The same would be true if you were quoting a range of time beginning and ending in specific years, for example:

> The First World War lasted from 1914 to 1918.

The exception to this would be if you were quoting actual years before our common era (BCE, sometimes referred to as BC). As these years are effectively counted backwards from the beginning of the Gregorian calendar, earlier years are larger "numbers" than more recent years, for example:

> The Maccabean Revolt lasted from 167 to 160 BCE.